# ReadTheDocs generates PDFs without my HTML tables

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, html-table, read-the-docs

We are converting a sizeable document for hosting on ReadTheDocs. We weren't happy with the simple presentation enabled by Markdown table syntax, so we coded our tables as HTML. Very nice in the HTML viewer (e.g., the end of http://manual.cytoscape.org/en/latest/Command_Line_Arguments.html).

In the PDF version generated by ReadTheDocs, each of our tables is completely missing (see page 9 on https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/cytoscape-working-copy/latest/cytoscape-working-copy.pdf).

Have we made a mistake by coding tables as HTML? Could we have taken a different route and gotten nice tables in both HTML *and* PDF?

Any advice would be helpful ...

Thanks!

Comment: That <div> would be perfect for what http://www.cloudfornatter.com/css2pdf was designed to do. I am an author and pages like that are why we created the application.

Comment: Kevin ... thanks for pointing this out. I think I see that css2pdf will convert in-vivo web content to a PDF. That's not quite the use case here. As far as I'm aware, ReadTheDocs converts the .MD files to either HTML or PDF. The HTML route is fine, and as my tables are HTML-formatted, all is good. It seems to be dropping the HTML-formatted tables when going the PDF formatting route.So, for css2pdf to apply here, it would have to somehow be activated by ReadTheDocs during the MD-to-PDF conversion process. I'm not seeing how to wire css2pdf into that. Can you explain further? Thanks!

Comment: You are likely correct if your concept is to send some unique markup with (maybe) CSS to some application to create it. If you put a button on that page that said "PDF" me ... then you would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used ReadTheDocs myself, but from reading their [Getting Started](http://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) guide, I assume you are using Sphinx? While Markdown supports embedding raw HTML, Sphinx does not support converting it to other formats.

You should consider moving to reStructuredText (Sphinx's native markup format), as it is much more advanced than Markdown. It can even be extended with custom directives and roles, should you need this. But be sure to first check whether [reStructuredText tables](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#tables) offer the flexibility you require. [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org) can convert your Markdown files to reStructuredText.

I see you are using a table to document command line options. reStructuredText supports documenting command line options using [option lists](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#option-lists). In theory, you could change how option lists are represented in the output document, but this might not be easy to accomplish, especially for PDF output using LaTeX (shameless plug: using [rinohtype](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/) for PDF output should make this much easier in the future).

Comment: Thanks, Brecht ... a fair suggestion, and I appreciate the advice. I'll look into reStructuredText to see how far it gets us.